# How can my route use optional parameters in the middle of the URL using ASP MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I would like my URLs to use the convention:

```
/{controller}/{id}/{action}
```

rather than

```
/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

I tried setting up a route as follows:

```cs
routes.MapRoute(
            "Campaign",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Campaign", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );
```

But this doesn't work because I am unable to make the id parameter optional.

The following URLs **do work**:

```
/campaign/1234/dashboard
/campaign/1234/edit
/campaign/1234/delete
```

But these URLs **do not**:

```
/campaign/create
/campaign/indexempty
```

MVC just calls `Index` for both. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you probably need two separate routes for this.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "CampaignDetail",
            "{controller}/{id}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Campaign", action = "Index" } 
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            "Campaign",
            "{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Campaign", action = "Index" } 
        );
```

Comment: That worked! Slight modification to your code--I named the first route "CampaignDetail" so that it wouldn't conflict with the second route.

Comment: Oh, I missed that.  I'm glad it helped.

Comment: One more thing--Having `{controller}/{id}/{action}` interfered with my default route. I was able to fix this by explicitly using the word **campaign** in my url. i.e. `campaign/{id}/{action}`.