# Config routes as to set the method after the parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to send the next to a `C#` controller:

`www.page.com/app/codes/10/status`

The parameter is `10` and `status` is the method.

if I send `www.page.com/app/codes/status/10` the status before the parameter is working fine, but not in the other way.

I tried to configure the routes to be like

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "codes",
url: "{controller}/{id}/status",
defaults: new { controller = "codes", action = "Status", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "codes",
url: "codes/{id}/status",
defaults: new { controller = "codes", action = "Status", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

but none of them is working.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: With `{id}` being in the middle of your route, I don't think it can be optional. Try removing the `UrlParameter.Optional`.

Comment: Show controller action and also where you configure route in relation to other routes.

Comment: I've found this for MVC 3 - [How can my route use optional parameters in the middle of the URL using ASP MVC3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314148/how-can-my-route-use-optional-parameters-in-the-middle-of-the-url-using-asp-mvc3) - it's possible it's improved in a new version, but maybe you need two routes.

Comment: Thanks guys, It was this remove the `UrlParameter.Optional` and also move to the first rule, Thanks, A lot.

Comment: @TiGreX glad you figured it out. either add it as an answer so as not to leave the question open or delete the question all together.

Comment: @Nkosi I going to wait if some of the guys wants to enter the answer and I will accept it, if not I will write the answer. I guess this can be a common question for the community.

Comment: @TiGreX if you have the answer you might as well post it yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found thanks to @John @Nkosi and @Kobi

Basically from this one remove `id = UrlParameter.Optional`

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "codes",
url: "{controller}/{id}/status",
defaults: new { controller = "codes", action = "Status" }
);
```

also i moved this route to the first place.

and its working fine.